# Anatomically Correct Marine Griffin

Tags: anatomy, mythical-creatures, anatomically-correct

The marine griffin is a variety of griffin found in heraldry. It has the foreparts of an eagle, with 2 wings and 2 talons as forelegs, and a limbless hindpart like a fish or serpent.

[image]

It should be able to swim, fly, and catch prey with its talons

Their limb arrangement seems remarkably close to that of advanced fish, though with a more tetrapodal structure to the limbs themselves

Given this feature, could such a marine griffin exist within the standard anatomies of vertebrates?

Comment: *"The marine griffin is [...] found in heraldry":* Example of a coat of arms featuring said beast?

Comment: I would like to see that too.  I know of hippogriffs as featured in Harry Potter and hippocampi which have horse heads and no wings.  I have not seen a marine gryphon that I can remember.  And for good or bad I remember such things.

Comment: @AlexP Found a wikipedia page von Deutchland :). Here it is : https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischgreif

Comment: @IchthysKing It can be helpful to provide the references (you must have some to dig so peculiar creatures!). It'll prevent people from looking everywhere on the web to have a better idea of what this mythological/legendical creature is ^^'.

Comment: @Tortliena: Thank you so much!

Comment: We will need a German Heraldry tag if there's many more gems like this hiding out there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this Q because it violates the rules of the [Anatomically Correct Series](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609). The "creature" in question has never been expressed in the context of being real (it's not a myth, it's not been written about in stories interacting with humanity, nothing). There is nothing about this "creature" to describe it's existence other than the heraldic image. But worst of all, you ***know*** the limits of this series, Ichthys.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact Is that the entire basis for casting your vote? Do you think "By a literal, strict interpretation of the rules, this question is incorrectly phrased" is a good enough reason for closure?

Comment: Yes, Ichtys... That's the whole point of having rules, ordinances, regulations, and laws. If you don't want to follow the rules, go ask your questions on Reddit. We've had a lot of trouble with you asking any old darn thing you want and then complaining when it doesn't meet the expectations for how this Stack is used. Follow the rules, my friend, or take your questions were there are no rules.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact The only purpose of rules is to maintain order and usability, not just to catch people out with wordplay. There's a reason why places like Wikipedia have an Ignore All Rules policy

Comment: Funny you should say "order and usability." From the ACS question we read, "Due to a large amount of low quality question[s] using this series' formula..." Why do we have rules? To avoid low quality questions like this one and improve the order and usability of the Stack. And we do not have an Ignore All Rules policy. You're welcome to post on any of Wikipedia's talk pages, though. Might be interesting to see how quickly that policy is embraced.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact What is wrong with this question, quality-wise? Why does the fact that it technically doesn't meet the strict definition for the series it's been put in, make it so poor and unacceptable?

Comment: (a) You're inventing all of the criteria, rather than finding criteria from existing sources (which is the intent of ACS). (b) What criteria you've provided is woefully insufficient for anything other than trivial answers. ACS once had a series of amazing questions and answers where the creature in question was *well-defined* from either fictional literature or mythology. Now it's filled with low-quality stuff like this: a request to anatomically rationalize a heraldic line drawing.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact (a) Is it really so atrocious to assume that eagle-like parts work like eagles? And the whole name of the game here to add on criteria, is it not? I doubt that any myths involving kappa or snallygasters involved the mystery of their evolution. (b) I don't see how a question that's a few steps from "Can a haddock with wings fly?" is in any way trivial

Comment: @JBH [So tags -whose main purpose is to categorize questions- are more important than the content in determining whether a question is to be accepted, now](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)? Besides, Ichthys's not "inventing all of the criteria" for a [non-fictional](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fictional) creature, as it is asked on the anatomically-correct main page (how to describe "fictional" or mythological creatures). Among other things, physical description is what's on the picture, even though we lack some "behavioral traits". [...]

Comment: [...] Behavioral traits, which... By the way encompass a bit what you can see on many other questions of this type, because that's what folklore and legends are : To the exception of the most famous ones, they **all** are blurry in details in many aspects. Now then, the question might be lacking details or they're moving forward speculations, but I'd rather close the question for any of the default reasons or editing its tags if it's so important than closing it because it uses one wrong tag.

Comment: @Tortliena (a) Where in these comments did I mention anything about tags? That's entirely new to me and in no way the problem I have with the post. (b) My complaint is that it's yet another low-quality ACSish post by Ichy. The whole point of ACS is to NOT speculate about the behaviors, but to use established behaviors from literature to speculate on the possible anatomy of a creature. If you don't accept this, then you're suggesting there's no difference between the ACS and any other [tag:creature-design] question. *There's supposed to be a difference.*

Comment: @JBH (a) That's what ACs is, basically. It's just a category of questions. And your first comment *is* complaining about it being an AC. (b) Yes, the difference is that it's rooted somewhere else. Now, tell me : what in the description "eagle with fish leg **heraldry**" is *not* rooted elsewhere and is pure invention?Please check back what the definition of "fictional" is. Moreover : "*it is the questioner's responsibility to invent the creature*". Straight from the ACs source.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you anymore, @Tortliena. This question sucks and Ichy's behavior has been going on for a long time. I'll leave you with the last word, but I'll express the same idea to you I expressed to him: if you don't want rules, go to a service that doesn't have any. (Let's see, +5/-5 voting, 4/5 close votes... I don't appear to be alone in my principles...)

Comment: @JBH I'm not wanting no rules, but your rules and the rules stated on the AC post are fundamentally not the same. Please [read back the meta-post for the close-reasons](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/80336) you should give instead of telling "This AC question sucks". I don't think it's wise at all to close it as being a 'bad' anatomically-correct question. This makes no sense and is objectively unhelpful, in contrario to telling "you're not giving enough details" or "it's opinion-based".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try the Keel

This anatomy could work by invoking the avian sternum

Specifically, the ichthyoid pelvis, sitting under the breast, would articulate with an extenstion of the keel. The best solution would likely be a synarthrosis along the length of the pelvis, or at least at multiple key points. This solidly attached pelvic girdle could quite well support the talons enough for this marine griffin to snatch up its prey

Such an anatomy is already attested to, at least in part, in real vertebrates: The pelvis of rayed fish is in two halves, jointed together. On the sternum, we have the clavicle and other such bones which demonstrate a linkage between the sternum and the limb girdles

Answer (score 3):

### Soar like an albatross, fischgrief!

[image]

[image]

How many underwater species have eagle like feathers? None, because the nice big splayed feathers that are so good for flight are bad for sustained wetting. They don't keep the eagle parts warm.

Either it'd have to
a) Be like kestrels and sea eagles and only have limited exposure to water (but then the fish tail makes no sense), or

b) Have tightly packed streamlined feathers like gulls or penguins.

So I think albatrosses,seagulls (and maybe penguins) should be your model; albatrosses are pretty darned marine-griffin-like when you have your "What looks like a marine griffin" hat on.

Comment: Maybe the marine griffin could put its legs together while swimming to temporarily make the big tail? The tail's a problem, just not as big a problem as lungs and feathered, flapping wings for a fish, IMO.